# Unexpected behavior when I duplicate rows in data frame with a new structure

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this (test file, the real one is bigger):

```
og  cogs    consensus   p_function  category    gene_1  gene_2  t   dnds    dn  ds
OG0000190   COG0593 99 / 99 Chromosomal replication initiation ATPase DnaA (DnaA)   L   apS2gMQ_00001   GAWBhUD_01925   0.0194  0.126   0.0021  0.0163
OG0000190   COG0593 99 / 99 Chromosomal replication initiation ATPase DnaA (DnaA)   L   apS2gMQ_00001   GcPBA0T_00001   0.0174  0.001   0   0.0168
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) MV  JdgVjSO_00092   IlhnQ8K_01601   0.0244  0.1508  0.0027  0.0181
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) MV  JdgVjSO_00092   IsqAoZB_00822   0.0359  0.1083  0.0029  0.0265
OG0000532   COG0534 99 / 99 Na+-driven multidrug efflux pump, DinF/NorM/MATE family (NorM)  V   pr2jcFN_01326   528cT6K_01654   0.1306  0.1176  0.013   0.1105
OG0000532   COG0534 99 / 99 Na+-driven multidrug efflux pump, DinF/NorM/MATE family (NorM)  V   GcPBA0T_00567   7QtjQYC_01559   0.0502  0.1786  0.0067  0.0373
OG0000223   2DSC2   99 / 99 NO_COG_HIT  NO_COG_HIT  HQyC1X2_00055   BDcxYt7_01158   0.0083  99  0.0053  1e-04
OG0000223   2DSC2   99 / 99 NO_COG_HIT  NO_COG_HIT  kNAVz3k_01037   7QtjQYC_00282   0.0083  99  0.0053  1e-04
```

I wrote a python script to read every row and check in the fifth column ('category'). The main goal is to check if in that column there is a category with more than one letter, for example, MV in my data frame. If that happens, the "if" statement takes the row and duplicates it. The "else" part checks if 'NO_COG_HIT' is present.
In fact, the script works and creates a new data frame while duplicating the row when a category has more than one letter.
However, I want to do that without repeating the same two letters, I want to separate them. For example, my actual output in that row (with more than one letter):

```
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) MV  JdgVjSO_00092   IlhnQ8K_01601   0.0244  0.1508  0.0027  0.0181
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) MV  JdgVjSO_00092   IsqAoZB_00822   0.0359  0.1083  0.0029  0.0265
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) MV  JdgVjSO_00092   IsqAoZB_00822   0.0359  0.1083  0.0029  0.0265
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) MV  JdgVjSO_00092   J02zmKx_01401   0.0162  0.121   0.0014  0.0118
```

The row is present 4 times (at the beginning were 2), but the letter is still the same "MV".
My expected output is (the letter will be separate, "M" and "V"):

```
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) M   JdgVjSO_00092   IlhnQ8K_01601   0.0244  0.1508  0.0027  0.0181
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) M   JdgVjSO_00092   IlhnQ8K_01601   0.0244  0.1508  0.0027  0.0181
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) V   JdgVjSO_00092   IsqAoZB_00822   0.0359  0.1083  0.0029  0.0265
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) V   JdgVjSO_00092   J02zmKx_01401   0.0162  0.121   0.0014  0.0118
```

My script:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load data frame
test_file = pd.read_csv("/path/test.tsv",
                        sep="\t", names=['og', 'cogs', 'consensus', 'p_function', 'category', 'gene_1', 'gene_2', 't',
                                         'dnds', 'dn', 'ds'])

# Sets the variable rows to the index of the data frame
rows = test_file.index

# Set a new data frame
new_test_file = pd.DataFrame(columns=['og', 'cogs', 'consensus', 'p_function', 'category', 'gene_1', 'gene_2', 't',
                                      'dnds', 'dn', 'ds'])

# Iterate over the rows in the data frame's index
for r in rows:
    # Extract the value of "category" column for the current 'r' (row) and assigns it to the variable
    join_cog = test_file.at[r, 'category']
    # Check if the value in join_cog variable is not equal to 'NO_COG_HIT', if is not, it will execute
    if (join_cog!= 'NO_COG_HIT'):
        for letter in join_cog:
            cog = letter
            og = test_file.at[r, 'og']
            cogs = test_file.at[r, 'cogs']
            consensus = test_file.at[r, 'consensus']
            p_function = test_file.at[r, 'p_function']
            category = test_file.at[r, 'category']
            gene_1 = test_file.at[r, 'gene_1']
            gene_2 = test_file.at[r, 'gene_2']
            t = test_file.at[r, 't']
            dnds = test_file.at[r, 'dnds']
            dn = test_file.at[r, 'dn']
            ds = test_file.at[r, 'ds']
            df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'og': [og], 'cogs': [cogs], 'consensus': [consensus], 'p_function': [p_function],
                                   'category': [category], 'gene_1': [gene_1], 'gene_2': [gene_2], 't': [t],
                                   'dnds': [dnds], 'dn': [dn], 'ds': [ds]})
            new_test_file = pd.concat([new_test_file, df_tmp], ignore_index=True)
    # If 'NO_COG_HIT' is present, it will execute
    else:
        cog = letter
        og = test_file.at[r, 'og']
        cogs = test_file.at[r, 'cogs']
        consensus = test_file.at[r, 'consensus']
        p_function = test_file.at[r, 'p_function']
        category = test_file.at[r, 'category']
        gene_1 = test_file.at[r, 'gene_1']
        gene_2 = test_file.at[r, 'gene_2']
        t = test_file.at[r, 't']
        dnds = test_file.at[r, 'dnds']
        dn = test_file.at[r, 'dn']
        ds = test_file.at[r, 'ds']
        df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'og': [og], 'cogs': [cogs], 'consensus': [consensus], 'p_function': [p_function],
                               'category': [category], 'gene_1': [gene_1], 'gene_2': [gene_2], 't': [t],
                               'dnds': [dnds], 'dn': [dn], 'ds': [ds]})
        new_test_file = pd.concat([new_test_file, df_tmp], ignore_index=True)
```

I'm looking to solve this unexpected behavior.

Comment: It seems as though nothing is done with `cog = letter`? Should that be true?

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, maybe you are right because I didn't define that variable. Let me check

Comment: It is assumed that the variable, #store the single letter in another variable. However, I don't know what more to do

Comment: Shouldn't `category = letter`?

Comment: shouldn´t be, because ```category``` is for letter representation (for example, M or V) and cogs is for ```cog+N°```

Comment: Then I fail to understand what NO_COG_HIT means. In your question it seemed related to MV?

Comment: if the value in the fifth column is```NO_COG_HIT```, the first if statement check for letters in that column, for example, M. If the category has a combination of more than one letter, for example, MV. The row will be duplicate and separate the letter, separating M and V in two different rows. Else, ```NO_COG_HIT``` is present the row is added in the new data frame. The important is when MV or other combination of letter is present

Comment: I just don't see any logic that either puts M or V in that column. What is your logic behind it? Right now both the if and the else do the exact same apart from iterating over the letters and doing nothing with it.

Comment: I find the issue, was related to your initial idea. Thank you for the comment! @BRemmelzwaal

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I forgot to put the variable letter instead of category when I create the new data frame:

```
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'og': [og], 'cogs': [cogs], 'consensus': [consensus], 'p_function': [p_function],
                                   'category': [letter], 'gene_1': [gene_1], 'gene_2': [gene_2], 't': [t],
                                   'dnds': [dnds], 'dn': [dn], 'ds': [ds]})
```

In the line where: `'category': [category]` (original script), must be: `'category': [letter]`, so the output (correct) will be this one (when there is more than 1 letter in the category column):

```
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) M   JdgVjSO_00092   IlhnQ8K_01601   0.0244  0.1508  0.0027  0.0181
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) V   JdgVjSO_00092   IlhnQ8K_01601   0.0244  0.1508  0.0027  0.0181
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) M   JdgVjSO_00092   IsqAoZB_00822   0.0359  0.1083  0.0029  0.0265
OG0000335   COG0845 99 / 99 Multidrug efflux pump subunit AcrA (membrane-fusion protein) (AcrA) V   JdgVjSO_00092   IsqAoZB_00822   0.0359  0.1083  0.0029  0.0265
OG0000335   COG0845 99 /
```

Comment: But this was exactly what I meant in my comment "Shouldn't `category = letter?`"... Anyway, glad you could solve your issue.